# NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error at data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I'm currently getting a "connection not private error" over at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (using Chrome). I have verified that my date and time settings are correct, and another user has confirmed receiving the same error.

[image]

Comment: "It’s likely the website’s certificate is expired, which prevents Firefox from connecting securely." on Firefox.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8TQ7.png

Comment: I'm getting it too, on Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: We're investigating it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be resolved.

Unfortunately, the system that we set up to push the certs automatically failed in this case. We poked it very hard to get it working again.

Comment: Is it "push the certs automatically" or "automatically failed"? :P Thanks for taking care of things!

Comment: This answer doesn't explain *why* the system failed (virus? capitalization mismatch? someone forgot to schedule it?) or what exactly has been done to prevent a recurrence.